# How do I test an xbox 360 slim power brick?

Tags: power-supply, voltage

I've looked everywhere and I just want an answer to a simple question. I have an xbox 360 slim and 2 power bricks I am trying to fix. I also have a multimeter. I know the power supply is meant to output 5 volts and 12 volts but with both of the power bricks I only get a 5 volt readying, the 12 volt line doesn't even register. and I am wondering, seeing as this is the case with both power bricks, does the 12 volt line not activate until it is plugged into the xbox?

No matter where I look no one seems to be able to help me so lets see if i can get some responses here.

Comment: Some power supplies communicate with their devices and may change their behavior based on the conversation. However, determining what an xbox power supply does specifically is off topic here; that's a question for a forum about xboxen. Given the proprietary nature of the hardware it's unlikely and answer is available, unless you can find someone who has reverse-engineered the design, or are willing to do it yourself.

Answer (score 3):

There is conflicting information online, but the gist is that the XBox 360 PSU has a power enable pin (Pin 7). The PSU will only provide 5v power, which is the XBox 360 standby power source, until the power enable pin is activated by the Xbox (When you go to turn the Xbox "on"). Until then, 12v is disabled.

The **conflicting information** is what you need to do with the Power Enable pin. Some say you need to tie it to ground, some say tie it to 3.3v, and some say it can be tied directly to the 5v standby source (I would use a resistor none the less). Since it is a proprietary power supply, everything we know about it is educated guesses about how it works by people tinkering and messing around with the Xbox. **Considering the high amperage, please be careful, you could kill yourself if you do the wrong thing.**

Search for `Xbox 360 "power enable" pin` on google for more information, at your own risk.

Comment: Thank you for the information, thats exactly what i needed!